# Show Pointers on the Google Map View

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-maps

I have tried to show the markers on the Google Map Layout. I have tried on this way but it not shows the markers on the map.

This method is working fine while showing the map first time. While the location is updated, new markers are not going to update on previously loaded map.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true"></script>
<script>
    var locations = [];
    var map;

    getLocations();

    function getLocations(){
        $.post("./../all_donors.php",
            {

            },
            function (data, status) {
                var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                for($j=0; $j<obj.length; $j++){
                    marker.push(new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: new google.maps.LatLng(obj[j]['latitude'], obj[i]['longitude']),
                        map: map
                    }));
                }
            });
    }

    function initialize() {

        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(9.6667,80.0000);
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 10,
            center: myLatlng
        }
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('page-wrapper'), mapOptions);

        var marker, i;

        for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
                map: map
            });

            // process multiple info windows
            (function(marker, i) {
                // add click event
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                        content: 'Doner Name: ' + locations[i][0] + '<br/>Blood Group: ' + locations[i][3]
                    });
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                });
            })(marker, i);

        }

    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);


</script>
```

Comment: It would be good to see which errors you're getting.

Comment: "it shows error." --- what error is it showing?  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, you call `getLocations` before `initialize` (or even set the event listener), and in `getLocations` you only append points to the map (which doesn't even exist yet), and not to your dedicated `positions` variable.

Since I don't know what your error message was, I cannot speculate further, but that is just one thing that I noticed.